# RC circuit - R/C ratio meaning

Tags: circuit-analysis

in all the analyses of the RC circuits (direct current) that I have seen, the governing term is R multiplied by C. For example:

$$\frac{V_{c}}{V_{in}}(s)=\frac{1}{1+RCs}$$

[image]

Obviously, there should be some effect of having a twice R and twice smaller C. What would be the effect of doing it?

Comment: Maybe, consider adding a 'circuit' to your question. You can use the edit button, and then use the build in Circuit Editor.

Comment: and you seem to have a formula. Insert the values there and see what happens. I mean, this is math – not magic! Be very careful with "should", as –unlike magic– math doesn't care about your emotional relation to it.

Comment: The voltage transfer function is not the only relevant property of this circuit. What happens if you compute its input and/or output impedances?

Comment: \$R \times C = \Omega \times \frac{Q}{V} = \frac{V}{I} \times \frac{I t}{V } = t\$ and the units of \$t = s\$ the is second

Comment: The R/C ratio would be ∞ (as in really large) regardless of R & C, so meaningless.

Comment: Calculate the energy dissipated in the resistor when charging the capacitor for, say, four time constants, for a large value of R, and a small value of R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you keep RC constant, then there will be no effect on behaviour of this circuit *in isolation*. Doubling R and halving C, for example, will have no effect, and the circuit's behaviour remains exactly the same.

As someone in the comments pointed out, a lot depends on what you connect to the output of that circuit. A lower value of R, and greater C, will have a lower output impedance, able to provide more current to whatever stage comes next.

The advantage in practical terms of increasing R is that you can use a smaller, cheaper capacitor, at the cost of slightly increased noise and susceptibility to interference like mains or electromagnetic pick-up. Using a larger capacitor might also force you to use a polarised electrolytic device, with all the associated concerns that raises.

On the other hand, still from a practical perspective, if you make the capacitance too small, so that its value becomes comparable with parasitic elements elsewhere, then you lose precision. For example, if your circuit uses a 10pF capacitor, and the PCB traces and other parasitic elements are of the order of many picofarads, then you cannot expect to achieve a precise time constant.

All this means that in theoretical analysis, and in isolation, the time constant RC can be obtained using *any* pair of values whose product is appropriate. In practice, there are other issues to consider.